# How to Fetch data using Vue Js laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

How do I fetch data using vue js and laravel . I have created vue component and controller.

Here is my database table structure 
[image]

```
<script>
export default {

    data(){
        return {
            kudos : []
        }
    },
    created(){
        axios.get('./api/kudos')
        .then(response => this.kudos = response.data);
    }
}
</script>
```

What I need to do is fetch the database data to blade file using vuejs .
Could someone guide me step by step?

1. Controller
2. Vue Component
3. Blade File

Comment: Do you have any additional code to show?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this?

**Controller:**

```
public function searchDatabase( Request $request )
{
    $foo = DB::table('bar')
        ->where([
            ["description", 'LIKE', "%{$request->input('query')}%"]
        ])
        ->limit(5)
        ->get();

    return response()->json($foo);
}
```

**YourComponent.vue**

```
<template>
    <div id="wrapper">

        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search database.." v-model="query" v-on:keyup="autoComplete" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="panel-footer" v-if="results.length">
            <table class="table table-sm">
                <tr v-bind:key="result" v-for="result in results">
                    <td> {{ result.description }} </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default{
        data(){
            return {
                query: '',
                url: '/search/blade/route',
                results: []
            }
        },
        methods: {
            autoComplete(){
                this.results = [];
                if(this.query.length > 2){
                    axios.get('/api/kudos', {params: {query: this.query}}).then(response => {
                        this.results = response.data;
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**search.blade.php**

```
<your-component></your-component>
```

Comment: Your `searchDatabase` function doesn't actually output anything.

Comment: Whoops! Good catch @ceejayoz . I just sterilized some existing code for this example and forgot to add that in.

Answer (score 0):

Add the name of your data in your response

```
 <script>
   export default {

    data(){
        return {
            kudos : []
        }
    },
    created(){
        axios.get('./api/kudos')
        .then(response => this.kudos = response.data.NameOfYourData);
    }
  }
</script>
```